# When get tensor from multiprocesses by torch.multiprocessing.Queue(), RuntimeError: Couldn't open shared event

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, queue, tensor

When the program runs to queue.get(), RuntimeError: Couldn't open shared event: <0000023F7034DF52>, error code: <2>.
While, if used numpy instead of tensor, the program works.
How to get torch.tensor from multiprocesses?

```
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def solve(queue):
    for i in range(3):
        queue.put(torch.ones((2, 2)))
        # queue.put(np.ones((2, 2))) #it works

def func():
    jobs = []
    queue = mp.Queue()

    for i in range(5):
        p = mp.Process(target=solve, args=(queue,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print('end')
    out = queue.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

Answer (score 1):

Torch tensors are passed as a file descriptor through a socket. Your error occurs when the producer process is finished before the consumer reads the tensor from the queue. One solution is to wait at the end of the consumer process until the tensors are read from the queue, which has been proposed here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-torch-tensor-over-multiprocessing-queue-process-fails/2847/2.

Another solution is to use the joinable queue and wait in the producer process using `queue.join()` until all tensors are successfuly obtained using the consumer; once the consumer obtains the tensor, you call `queue.task_done()`, as proposed here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-torch-tensor-over-multiprocessing-queue-process-fails/2847/10